# ng-grid grouping - Can I group rows in a grid based on a condition?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am trying to group a row based on a condition. I have 2 columns in my table, User and group.
If the value of group is blank, I want to keep those rows ungrouped.

[Trying to achieve this grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0FVr.png)

Right now the rows are also grouped for the rows where group value is blank.
[Current grouping which I have acheived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXykC.png)

Below is my grid, I have marked my column Group as a grouping.

```
        $scope.gridOptionsUserGroup = {
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        resize:false,
        enableSorting: true,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        enableSelectAll: true,
        enableRowSelection: true,
        enableFullRowSelection:true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection:true,
        enableGroupHeaderSelection: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        enableGridMenu: true,
        showGroupPanel: true,
        rowHeight: 30,      
        groups: ['grouping'],
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'grouping', displayName: 'Group' ,grouping: { groupPriority: 0 }, 
            sort: { priority: 1, direction: 'asc' }},
            { field: 'userName', displayName: 'User Name' }             
        ],          

    };
```

Comment: If you have given a try to it. than please provide snippet with plunker or fiddle otherwise it ill hard to help for anybody.

Comment: Added my code snippets. I have used the angularjs ng-grid grouping option.